# How to fix"warning: Do not use the development server in a production environment."

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7

When I try to run the code in Spyder (python2.7) , it immediately tells me that:

```
runfile('hereisthefilepath',wdir='path') 
Environment: production
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
Debug mode: off
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I will post the start of my code, I think the problem is because I connect to wrong environment, I should be in development environment.

I have already tried the code below:

```
export FLASK_APP=yourapp
export FLASK_ENV=development
flash run
```

however Spyder (python2.7) said there are syntax error at "Flask_APP" and"ENV"

Here is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash


currconn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxxx-dbs-xx.xx.xxxx.ca;Database=Anexample;UID=xx_xxxx;PWD=xxxxxxxxxxx')

currquery = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM dbo.vw_regions"
currcursor = currconn.cursor()
currcursor.execute(currquery)
```

Could any one help me out? with this error I can't run anything.

Comment: Have you asked anyone at your company about this?   It sounds like a custom error created there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will go and check. Just one more question, do you by any chance happen to know why it show there are syntax error for APP and ENV?

Comment: No I don't.  I'm not an expert in Python, just SQL Server.

Comment: Okay, thax anyway